# Realm Filter Query Always Shows Warning in Swift 5

Tags: swift, realm

*Swift 5, Xcode 11*

I have a bunch of Realm queries in my app that filter based on the presence of an `Optional` object.

For example:

```
//Class property
var currentWorkspace: Workspace?

//In viewDidLoad()
let objects = realm.objects(Entry.self).filter("workspace = %@", currentWorkspace)
```

I see the warning:

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'Workspace?' to 'Any'

...with some proposed solutions:

[image]

I've tried setting a default value and casting to `Any` but that's not really what I want. The only way I've found to get rid of the warning is to `guard` the `currentWorkspace` variable:

```
guard let workspace = currentWorkspace else { return }
```

Why can't I leave `currentWorkspace` as an `Optional`? Is this warning only because of the string interpolation that's going on?

Comment: Yes, the warning has nothing to do with Realm or the NSPredicate, it is simply caused by String interpolating an `Optional`.

Comment: The bigger question/issue is that when querying Realm, you have a finite set of objects you can query for; Realm supports the following property types: Bool, Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Double, Float, String, Date, and Data (or another Realm object that is one of those types). String, Date and Data properties can be optional so workspace is one of those? You want to be able to query for nil?